# how to replace the first message of p:growl primefaces

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets, growl

I want to use p:growl for the validation of inputs of [datatable row editing](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf)

but the problem is that the validation message is written twice on the p:growl

how can I replace the first by another text ("Error validation " or "Error conversion" for example) in the xhtml page (because this problem does not arise in the managed bean)

here is one of my columns :

```
 <p:column headerText="Commission" filterBy="#{car.commission}" style="width:25%">
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.commission}" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputText value="#{car.commission}" label="Commission" requiredMessage="Veuillez saisir une valeur"
            converterMessage="Veuillez saisir un nombre" validatorMessage="Veuillez saisir entre 0 et 100">
                <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0" maximum="100" />
            </p:inputText>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: You need to show your `<p:growl/>` here. Do you have `showDetail="true"` set on the component?

Comment: yes I have, `<p:growl id="messages"  showDetail="true" escape="false" life="2500" /> ` but I want to show both (summary and details) when I get message from managed bean => then I don't want to set showdetails to false

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the specific message you wish to customize (you're not clear on this), you should edit the contents of the **Messages.properties** file in `javax.faces` package of the *jsf-api.jar* that ships with your JSF2 bundle. I presume you wish to customize the converter summary and detail messages (based on your question history). To achieve this

1. Locate the `javax.faces.converter.DoubleConverter.DOUBLE` and `javax.faces.converter.DoubleConverter.DOUBLE detail` entries.
2. Depending on the local you're working with, edit the message entry for both keys and save the file

Comment: since I can edit the sumary from the managed bean why I cannot edit it from the current xhtml page

Comment: @atbegin-but you can't because it's not supported AFAIK. The messages need to be configured somewhere and then loaded into the placeholder

Comment: ok, thank you, then the only solution that I have now is to use el expression to changinh the value of showdetails attribute dynamicaly, what do you think ;), do you know a good tuto for that ?

Comment: @atbegin-but [`<h:outputFormat/>`](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-outputformat-example/) is a parameterized component used to dynamically generate static output